# What does `-e` option in sed do?

Tags: sed

I am trying to understand a shell script that uses `sed`. I found that there were some places where `sed` was invoked with the `-e` option.

I tried to see the `man` page and it just mentions,

> -e command
>
> Append the editing commands specified by the command argument to the list of commands.

which is not very clear to me.

Can someone kindly explain to me what the `-e` does? Thanks.

PS: I am using `sed` in mac

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **-e** parameters tells sed that you wish to supply multiple commands:

```
sed -e 's/string1/string2/g' -e 's/string4/string5/g'
```

This will replace **string1** with **string2** and **string4** with **string5**.

Comment: Thanks. That explains it. Now the cryptic message in the `man` command makes sense.

Comment: :-) glad to be of help

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It still does not truly reveal the true purpose of `-e` because the above script can be done similarly by: `sed 's/string1/string2/g;s/string4/string5/g' file`. Whatever separate expressions you have, you can fuse them into 1 expression and then drop the `-e`. Can somebody please reveal the necessity purpose of  `-e` in sed?

Comment: @daixtr It's explained in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33160/317243).